# МД5 на Objective-C

Tags: хеширование, objective-c, mobile-development, md5

Доброе время суток!
Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать МД5 со строки на Obj-c?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
```

**- 1 Вариант**

```
//NSString+MD5.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (MD5)

+ (NSString *)MD5:(NSString *)input;

@end

//NSString+MD5.m
#import "NSString+MD5.h"

@implementation NSString (MD5)

+ (NSString *)MD5:(NSString *)input {
    const char *cStr = [input UTF8String];
    unsigned char digest[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), digest );

    NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
    for(int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];
    }

    return  output;
}

@end
```

**- 2 Вариант**

```
//NSData+MD5.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSData (MD5)

- (NSString *)MD5;

@end

//NSData+MD5.m
#import "NSData+MD5.h"

@implementation NSData (MD5)

- (NSString *)MD5 {
    unsigned char digest[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CC_MD5([self bytes], [self length], digest);

    NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
    for(int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x",digest[i]];
    }

    return output;
}

@end
```

Comment: +1, но я бы всё же реализовывал md5 не строки, а бессемантичного массива байт.

Comment: А в чём разница будет?

Comment: @dev_nikita_ysacov: в семантике. Можно, например, содержимое mp3-файла представить в виде строки, но по смыслу это не строка, а просто набор байт.

@Ковальский: Набор байт, которых мы хотим прогнать через md5, может вполне содержать встроенные нули, но ваш код (`strlen(cStr)`) к этому не готов. Подправите?

Comment: @VladD

Вы говорите о такой реализации?
CC_MD5(self.bytes, self.length, digest);

Comment: @Ковальский: да, именно о ней.

Comment: @Ковальский, @VladD - Спасибо ребят! Ваш ответ помог!

Comment: @dev_nikita_ysacov

Не за что!